# RichTextBox prints new line upon receiving a certain character

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, textbox, richtextbox

I'd like to know if it is possible for the richtextbox or textbox multi lines to print in a new line upon receiving a certain character like "Z"?

I'm having a big time problem in getting values from a richtextbox. My microcontroller is sending a string in a non-constant speed to the C# program so any way that I use to extract the numbers from the string in a richtextbox is useless I think.

If my circuit sends this kind of string:
**Sensor1: 0.10 meter/s \nSensor2: 0.50 meter/s**
and then the c# program receives it and detects the **\n**, the next characters/string will be printed in a new line until it detects the another \n.

Is this possible? if not, what way can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a RichTextBox Control named `RichTextBox1`. Just replace your `\n` with `ControlChars.Lf`

Code in Visual Basic

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, "\n")
```

Code in C#

```
RichTextBox1.Text == RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, "\n")
```

You need to reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, parent of `ControlChars.Lf`. That goes without saying.

Comment: thank you so much!!! very nice answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :) Wait, I'll try it first before I accept this answer :P

Comment: ok marked as answer. :) my code:

richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\n");
            richTextBox1.Text += sMessage;

Comment: Glad I could help :) enjoy your day  buddy